# Define PFS Group in Strongswan IKEv2/IPsec Phase 2 Settings

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, tunnel, ipsec, strongswan

I am trying to setup a VPN connection on Ubuntu 20.04 using Strongswan. One of the requirements for the tunnel is to use PFS group 20.

Is the PFS group 20 being set when we have the following line in `ipsec.conf`?

```
  esp=aes256-sha512-ecp384
```

Thank you~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PFS (or rather Diffie-Hellman) group 20 for IKE/IKEv2 is the 384-bit random ECP group defined in [RFC 5903](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5903). So adding `ecp384` to the ESP proposal is correct.